# I need an example to run an update query in rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How would I perform the following update query in Rails? I would like to perform this with a single update query in the database. In pseudo-code, I would write:

```
update answers set user_id = @user.id where answered_by=@user.email and user_id = 0
```

In SQL it might be something like:

```
UPDATE `answers` SET user_id = '123' WHERE answered_by = 'email@example.com' and user_id = 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Answer.update_all(["user_id = ?", @user.id], ["answered_by = ? and user_id == ?", @user.email, 0])
```

Comment: Great thanks, I was doing this but I like you solution better

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) unless sql.blank?